# openerp rml formatting a table to be at the end of a page of invoice

Tags: python, xml, rml

I have a table which occurs after the item lines of an invoice. As the item lines vary in number from invoice to invoice, the table moves with it. I would like the table to stick to the bottom of the page. I saw a line call topPadder from , https://www.reportlab.com/examples/rml/test/test_008_tables.rml but doesn't work in OpenERP reports. Can anyone offer alternative solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but you can use `storyPlace` tag. You can define its width and height, and it x and y position.

It should look like this:

`<storyPlace x="35" y="660" width="525" height="73" origin="page">
    <!-- put your table here -->
 </storyPlace>`

For piece of example, see this [reportlab example](http://www.reportlab.com/examples/rml/test/test_000_catchforms.rml).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fit the table in the `header`section of the RML file. I´ve used this option but it only works in one page invoices (my old invoice structure, nowadays I use multi pages invoices).

```
<place x="1.0cm" y="1.0cm" width="19.0cm" height="2.0cm">
    <blockTable colWidths="X.X,X.X,X.X" style="YYY">
        <td>...</td>
    </blockTable>
<place>
```